# Real-time ECG filtering

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

[image]I am dealing with raspi3B+ and python 2.7.

I am using AD8232 heart rate sensor and MCP3008 analog-digital converter.

I am plotting the sensor data with matplotlib lib but it is too noisy.

I have to filter to ECG data but I did not know how to I apply.

Can I do filter real-time or I have to save the data into the txt file and then apply filtering,after filtering plotting data into the new txt file?

I did not save the data into the txt or csv file. How can I filter?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import spidev, time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
# read adc function
def analog_read(channel):
    r = spi.xfer2([1,(8+channel)<<4,0])
    adc_out = ((r[1]&3) << 8) + r[2]
    return adc_out
spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0,0)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
x = np.arange(500)
y=[0 for iii range(500)]
li, = ax.plot(x, y)
plt.ylim([0,3.3])
fig.canvas.draw()
plt.show(block=False)
# convert adc function
def St():
    for ii in range(1,501):
        reading = analog_read(0)
        voltage = reading * 3.3 / 4096
        time.sleep(0.005)
        vv=("%3.3f" % (voltage))
        x[ii-1]=ii-1
        y[ii-1]=vv
while True:
    St()
    li.set_ydata(y)
    fig.canvas.draw()
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to upload a screenshot of the plots you currently have ? It might help some people guiding you toward the right filtering !

Comment: Show us your python script

Comment: If I understand well, your program is 'real time', but you always has to wait until 500 values are filled? Important question before I give you answer - do you want to filter 500 values all at once or you want to filter real time way-> each value? I can show you, how to create realtime graph, updating after every new analog_read. Tell me what you wish and based on that I can show you simple way

Comment: @Martin Actually, I don’t want to wait filled 500 sample but I did not fix it. I don’t know how to create without waiting. Therefore, I want to filter real time way. Can you show me real-time graph and filtering without waiting? Thank you so much.

Comment: @RobinDupont I added a plot photo.

Comment: @YaseminY. I know, thats why I ask you about more details. Do you want real-time plotting(plot every read value) or batch(as you have it, every 500 values?)

Comment: @YaseminY. if any of the answers solved your question, this site works in a way that you 'Accept' the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script didnt work for me, so I will just add code, which you need to understand.

Your script doesnt perform real-time, but rather process data in batch of size 500 values. I changed the script to perform graph updating in realtime.

I used deque. I created from deque a buffer of size 500, so if you keep appending it from left, it will automaticly pop old values so if you keep ploting it, it will look realtime.

After you aqcuire  new value and before you plot the data every cycle, you have time to perform filtering - for example with Coarse graining method (you need to program it) or you just keep doing average based on previous few values.

**Your modified code**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import spidev, time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from collections import deque
# read adc function
def analog_read(channel):
    r = spi.xfer2([1,(8+channel)<<4,0])
    adc_out = ((r[1]&3) << 8) + r[2]
    return adc_out
spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0,0)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
x = np.arange(500)
x = x.tolist()
y=[0 for iii in range(500)]
li, = ax.plot(x, y)
plt.ylim([0,3.3])
fig.canvas.draw()
plt.show(block=False)
# convert adc function


voltage_series = deque([],maxlen=500)
x_axis = x.tolist()
#fill it
for i in range(500):
    voltage_series.append(0)

# Y-axis = voltage_series
# X-axis = x_axis

counter = 0
while True: # grapg updates every read
    time.sleep(0.05)
    reading = analog_read(0)
    voltage = reading * 3.3 / 4096
    vv=("%3.3f" % (voltage))

    voltage_series.appendleft(voltage)
    if counter%500==0:
    ### Time to realtime filtering
        voltage_for_filtering = list(voltage_series)
        # transfor to numpy for example np.array(voltage_for_filtering)
        # or do standard method for smoothing noise - coarse graining
        # voltage_for_filtering = coarse_grain(voltage_for_filtering) -->> example

        li.set_ydata(voltage_for_filtering)
        fig.canvas.draw()
```

Comment: I tried the code but it is too slow for plotting. Or how can I do filtering these every 500 values

Comment: My teacher’s tell me filtering every 500 sample. It seems like Real-time

Comment: I edited the answer. Now it reads 500 samples and then it plots